# Showing that $f\in C^n([0,\infty[)$ then $f(|\cdot|^2)$ in $C^n(\mathbb{R}^n).$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

Let $f$ a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f\in C^n([0,\infty[)$. If $|\cdot|:\mathbb{R}^n\to [0,\infty[$ with $|x|=\sqrt{x_{1}^2+\cdots+x_{n}^2}$, then $f(|\cdot|^2)$ is in $C^n(\mathbb{R^n})?$

I have that

$\frac{\partial }{\partial{x_i}}(a(|x|^2))=a'(|x|^2)2x_i$

and 
$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_j}}\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_i}}(a(|x|^2))=a^{''}(|x|^2)2^2x_i x_j$   if $j\neq i$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_j}}\frac{\partial }{\partial{x_i}}(a(|x|^2))a^{''}(|x|^2)2^2x_{i}^2+a'(|x|^2)2$ if $j=i$.

Therefore, up to this step, the partial derivatives are continuous.
How could one justify not having to do the cumbersome calculation?

Comment: Are you asking if the norm squared is continuous or if the composition is $n$ times differentiable?

Comment: the composition.

Comment: You have the same $n$ for the dimension of the domain and the degree of differentiability.

Comment: Chain rule, recall that a polynomial is infinitely many times differentiable.